# Javascript function that takes an array and returns a new array with each elements data types

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeof

so the directions are pretty simple yet I am finding myself stuck.

I have to create a function declaration that takes an array and returns a new array with each elements datatypes. this is what I am trying :

```
let arr = ["1",2,false,true];
let newArr = [];
function dataTypes (arr){



  for(i= 0; i < arr.length; i+=1 ){

    let y = typeOf(i)

    newArr.push(y);

  }
return newArr;
}

dataTypes (arr);
```

Comment: There is no `typeOf`, you need `typeof`, and it's an operator so `typeof i` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like:

```
let arr = ["1",2,false,true];

let res = arr.map(i => typeof(i));
```

A long-form version in plain JavaScript:

```
var res = arr.map(function(i) { return typeof(i) });
```

Though since you're using `let` the ES6 version should be better.

It looks like your original mistake was using `typeOf` instead of `typeof` where you should have gotten an error. Remember JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: doi! thank you! so fixed typeof...and now i get ['number','number','number]

Comment: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator, not a function. Just thought I'd clarify since the usage in this answer does not convey that. You can write `arr.map(i => typeof i)`, for example.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's kind of annoying that it's not a function or you could just `arr.map(typeof)` but such is not the case as you point out.

Comment: Also "better" deserves some explanation. Other than less code, why is an arrow function preferred to a function expression?

Comment: @RobG Readability is a huge concern here, the intent is clear. ES6 introduced these convenience features, so it's usually a good idea to use them unless you have specific constraints that prevent that. The "less is more" principle at work here. The most minimal solution, provided it's still abundantly understandable, is usually the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

[tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617077/10311524) has a good answer.

But if you want your version of code to run, here it is.

```
let arr = ["1", 2, false, true];
let newArr = [];
function dataTypes(arr) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    let y = typeof (arr[i])
    newArr = [...newArr, y]
  }
  return newArr;
}
dataTypes(arr);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't particularly helpful. The OP's code had a simple typo, fixing anything else is really just your opinion of a better way to write the code, which is subjective.